# In Java 8, how do I make a method reference to a method that takes no parameters and returns void?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have a bunch of methods with this signature:

```
public void sideEffects() {...}
public void foo() {...}
public void bar() {...}
```

(That is, they return void and take no parameters) And I'd like to be able to populate a List by doing something like this:

```
list.add(MyClass::sideEffects);
list.add(MyClass::foo);
list.add(MyClass::bar);
```

But, I'm unable to find a built in `@FunctionalInterface` in the `java.util.function` package that supports this signature.  Will I have to create my own `@FunctionalInterface` for this?

Comment: Method references are not objects. They are only usable in a context that expects an instance of some functional interface.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't understand your point.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: `I want to populate a List with method references` doesn't make much sense. You can say `I want to populate a List with instances of my functional interface`, but a method reference is not an object. Is is just a language construct that resolves to an object in the right context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok, I think I mean the second thing

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis see my edit.  Is that better?

Comment: You should put the declaration of `list` as well, basically describing that you want a functional interface method which takes no arguments and returns nothing. The `sideEffects` was good.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'd put the declaration if I knew it in advance, that's the point of the question.  I'm not sure how to declare the `List` because I don't know what `@FunctionalInterface` to use in its declaration.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, `java.lang.Runnable` has the signature you're looking for and is a `@FunctionalInterface`.  You can use this for this purpose, though I'm not sure if this is a good or bad practice.

The code will look like this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(Sandbox::sideEffects);
        list.add(Sandbox::foo);
        list.add(Sandbox::bar);

        for (Runnable runnable : list) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }

    public static void sideEffects() {
        System.out.println("sideEffects");
    }

    public static void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public static void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

}
```

Comment: You could also use `Callable<Void>`.

Comment: @maba Actually, that doesn't compile.  "Cannot convert void to java.lang.Void" on the `add` lines.  Am I doing something wrong?  All I changed was this: `List<Callable<Void>> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: This is perfectly good practice. The `Runnable` is the best solution here, and likely the reason it's not provided in the `java.util.function` package.

Comment: @tieTYT That doesn't compile because you are using a `void` as return type here, while the `Callable<Void>` expects a `Void` as return type.

Comment: Yes, `Runnable` is the thing to use. It's not in `java.util.function` since it already exists in `java.lang`.